# Making XSD elements optional in Infopath

Tags: xml, xsd

Since this is my first XSD, there are probably redundancies in the code, but my main issue is this:

I want senior_initials, senior_initials2 and junior_initials, junior_initials2 to be optional... (they are under elements senior_consultants and junior_consultants respectively.
The issue is that when i design an infopath form these elements are locked to "must have values", ie. they cant be empty...
Below is my full schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<!-- definition of simple elements --><!-- definition of simple elements -->
<xs:element name="description_short">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="250"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="description_medium"> 
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="520"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="description_long">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="3000"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element> 

<xs:element name="post_project"> 
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="1000"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="author" type="xs:string"/> <!-- Author of storycard -->

<xs:element name="senior_initials">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3})(\s[A-Z]{2}|\s[A-Z]{3})?"/> <!-- Must be UPPERCASE letters and space between each set of initials-->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="senior_initials2">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3})(\s[A-Z]{2}|\s[A-Z]{3})"/> <!-- Must be UPPERCASE letters and space between each set of initials-->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="senior_count" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>

<xs:element name="junior_initials">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3})(\s[A-Z]{2}|\s[A-Z]{3})?"/> <!-- Must be UPPERCASE letters and space between each set of initials -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="junior_initials2">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="([A-Z]{2}|[A-Z]{3})(\s[A-Z]{2}|\s[A-Z]{3})?"/> <!-- Must be UPPERCASE letters and space between each set of initials -->
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="junior_count" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>

<xs:element name="orglevel">
 <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Corporate"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Division"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Business Unit"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Team/Product"/>
    </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="service">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Cascading Strategy"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Executing Projects"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Managing the Organization"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="startdate">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}"></xs:pattern> <!-- format DD/MM/YYYY -->
            <xs:length value="10"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="enddate">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="\d{2}[/]\d{2}[/]\d{4}"></xs:pattern> <!-- format DD/MM/YYYY -->
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="confidential">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Yes"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="No"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="company" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:element name="department" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:element name="sector">
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Energy"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Materials"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Industrials"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Consumer discretionary"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Consumer staples"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Life sciences"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Financial services"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Information technology"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Communication services"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Utilities"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Real estate"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Other"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Other_sector_description" type="xs:string"/>

<xs:element name="Domain">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Cyber Security"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Digitilization"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Other"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="Other_domain_description" type="xs:string"/>


<xs:element name="revenue"> <!-- Millions of DKK -->
  <xs:simpleType>
   <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
     <xs:enumeration value="1-50"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="50-250"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="250-1000"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="1000-5000"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="5000-15000"/>
     <xs:enumeration value="15000+"/>
   </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>



<xs:element name="employees"> <!-- Number of employees -->
  <xs:simpleType>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="1-50"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="50-500"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="500-2000"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="2000-5000"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="5000-10000"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="10000+"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>



<!-- definition of attributes -->
<xs:attribute name="casename" type="xs:string"/>

<!-- definition of complex elements --><!-- definition of complex elements -->
<xs:element name="descriptions">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="description_short"/>
            <xs:element ref="description_medium"/>
            <xs:element ref="description_long"/>
            <xs:element ref="post_project"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="senior_consultants">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="senior_initials"/>
      <xs:element ref="senior_initials2"/>
      <xs:element ref="senior_count"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="junior_consultants">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="junior_initials"/>
      <xs:element ref="junior_initials2"/>
      <xs:element ref="junior_count"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="project">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="orglevel"/>
      <xs:element ref="service"/>
      <xs:element ref="Domain"/>
      <xs:element ref="Other_domain_description"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:element name="date">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="startdate"/>
      <xs:element ref="enddate"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="client">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
     <xs:element ref="company"/>
     <xs:element ref="confidential"/>
     <xs:element ref="sector"/>
     <xs:element ref="Other_sector_description"/>
     <xs:element ref="department"/>
     <xs:element ref="revenue"/>
     <xs:element ref="employees"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="storycard">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="descriptions"/>
      <xs:element ref="client"/>
      <xs:element ref="project"/>
      <xs:element ref="date"/>
      <xs:element ref="senior_consultants"/>
      <xs:element ref="junior_consultants"/>
      <xs:element ref="author"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="casename" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an element optional (i.e. the element can be omitted) add `minOccurs="0"`, for example

```
<xs:element ref="senior_initials" minOccurs="0"/>
```

To make it emptiable (i.e. to permit `<senior_initials/>` with no content), just make sure that the simple type allows a zero-length string as one of the permitted values.

I worry slightly about giving you such basic information. If you haven't studied the language in enough depth to know the answer to this question, then you probably shouldn't be coding until you have done more reading. It's a difficult language with some difficult concepts, not one you can learn by trial and error.

Comment: Thanks Michael 
I previously tried minOccurs="0" where it didnt seem to work, I re-did most of the code and used minOccurs which now works.
I added all my elements as simpleType before, I suspect thats where it went wrong.